# Pluralising 'Red Kite'

Tags: grammatical-number, animals

Is the following grammatically correct?

> An area frequented by red kite and skylarks

It would appear to be incorrect as *red kite* should be pluralised to *red kites*, however this sounds wrong to my ear.

Is this a grey-area? Or is it definitely incorrect?

Another example usage:

> There were sitings of red kite.

Comment: "An area frequented by red kite**s** and skylarks." is the sentence you want. I'm not sure why it sounds wrong to your ear.

Comment: It used to be common to use the singular as a plural for animals and especially for birds. I would have no problem with _We saw Red Kite, Plover, Moorhen, Bearded Tit and a lone Buzzard._

Comment: You should be consistent -- if it's singular for "red kite" it should be singular for "skylark".

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think that's misplaced pedantry. I'm not an ornithologist, so I'm not familiar with how often the singular is used to represent the "collective bird type" for each individual species, but it doesn't seem unreasonable to suppose those people who *are* in that business will be aware of usage differences on that front. Even from *my* perspective, it seems likely this would happen more often with, say, *I like **duck*** than *I like **blackbird*** (yeah - I know that confuses the issue because of the *foodstuff* connotations).

Comment: Both being plural or singular sound right to me, one of each does not.

Answer (score 4):

There are animals, like *moose* and *fish*, where the plural noun in English is identical to the singular one, and perhaps "kite" sounds like it should belong in that category to your ear, but every source I've seen pluralizes *kite* as *kite**s***.

Answer (score 4):

Consider...

> [*Greenfinch and **red kite** are birds belonging to the finch and kite families respectively*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ekd_75VRAJoC&pg=PA30&dq=%22red%20kite%20are%20birds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PRAHVcW6FdTB7AaiyoCwCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22red%20kite%20are%20birds%22&f=false)
>
> [***Red kite** are birds of prey that like to collect things with which to decorate their nests*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wxPdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT147&dq=%22red%20kite%20are%20birds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PRAHVcW6FdTB7AaiyoCwCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22red%20kite%20are%20birds%22&f=false)

Personally I don't see anything particularly unusual about such usages in a "species identification" context. We can't do this with *all* "living creature" identifiers (no-one ever says ***Cow are** important to dairy farmers*), but for some of them *(sheep, fish, moose, squid)* "everybody knows" these words can be both singular and plural. To me, (living) *kite* can certainly fall into that category.

Comment: Thanks. You've hit the nail on the head. It is exactly this context which is making me uneasy.

Comment: @Pedr: Your first citation is interesting in that respect. As I said, I don't see anything particularly unusual there, because it's obviously more of a reference to *the **species** collectively*, rather than *[an unspecified number of] **individual birds***. I can't say that's because I'm familiar with the specific word ***kite*** being used that way, since on the rare occasions ***I*** use that word I'm only usually talking about a single bird anyway. But *your* writer "switched mode" with ***skylarks***...

Comment: ...Would I have seen anything more unusual if he'd chosen to write *...frequented by **skylark** and **red kites**?* Possibly, but I wouldn't like to say for sure. And by now it's getting to be like when you can't smell the gas leak after a few minutes because your nose has got "tired". My "inner grammarian" can only detect such fine nuances for a short time before it just gets confused.

Comment: I think I would have used `the` as in `"The greenfinch and red kite..."`. Somehow, when I hear "the" I understand that the entire species is being grouped into a singular and it doesn't sound strange.

Comment: @ArtB: There's definitely a difference between ***The owl** is a solitary hunter*, where it's a singular reference denoting ***all*** owls "collectively", and ***Red kite** are often seen here*, where it means *[some] specimens **of that species***. But I'm not sure *exactly* why I have no problem with OP's usage, whereas I would find *An area frequented by **owl** and red kite* more than a trifle weird. Maybe it's just that in my "ordinary, non-naturalist world", I'm more likely to talk about *an owl, two owls*. So to me, owls are usually *actual birds* rather than just a species designation.

Answer (score -1):

The plural of kite is kites, whether it's a toy or a bird.
See it in use in the first paragraph here: http://www.bto.org/about-birds/bird-of-month/red-kite

Comment: From the first line of the page you link to: 'Show the map (right) to a silver-haired birdwatcher and the chances are that they will recognise the distribution as being that of Red Kite'.

Comment: @Pedr Indeed: that article inconsistently uses both "kite" and "kites" as the plural.

Comment: Fair cop! But you'll find that all through the BTO site, they use the plural for multiple birds, and the singular when it refers to the species (so, in this case, they should have "the Red Kite"). But you're right, it was a weak example.

Comment: Pleasingly, I see the RSPB offers a toy kite in the shape of the red kite, with "information about red kites". http://shopping.rspb.org.uk/gifts-home/garden-outdoors/outdoors/flying-red-kite.html